# Applying excel formula using openpxl to column takes ages to execute

Tags: python, excel, performance, formula

Here is the code:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/abc.xlsx')
Sheet = wb['Data Owner Group History']

for cellObj in list(Sheet.columns)[12]:

    #   print(n)
    j1=('J'+str(cellObj.row))
    j2 = ('J'+str((cellObj.row)+1))
    y=('K'+(str((cellObj.row)+1)))
    k=('K2'+(str(cellObj.row)))
    n='IF(AND({0}="SC",{1}="XXX-ZZZ-DISPATCH (xxxx/xxx group)"),{2}- 
    {3},"")'.format(j1,j2,y,k)
    cellObj.value = n
    wb.save("C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Time to Dispatch 07-27-2018.xlsx")
    print("done")
```

In simpler words, i need to apply a formula to whole column, but it consumes only cpu usage and produces no result.

Please suggest some fix or alternative.

Comment: When you say "produces no result",  do you mean that the file C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Time to Dispatch 07-27-2018.xlsx is not created? Or it is a blank workbook? Or what?

Comment: It gets created, but when i open it, the file is damaged and i get only blank sheet. Python shows running file and never prints the last message i.e., print("done")

Comment: Have you examined the contents of `j1`, `j2`, `y`, `k`, and `n` when you are running the code? Are they what you ex[pected?